# Customizing Save File Dialog of Printing

Tags: c#

I want to set the File Name for Save file dialog that appears when print button is clicked.
I've tried this. And it does not work. (File Name does not changed)!
Can sommeone tell me any idea.

```
PrintDocument pd = rep.Document;
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
DialogResult userResp = printDialog.ShowDialog();
if (userResp == DialogResult.OK)
{
       pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
       SaveFileDialog pdfSaveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
       pdfSaveDialog.FileName = "MyNewReport";
       pdfSaveDialog.Filter = "PDF File|*.pdf";
       userResp = pdfSaveDialog.ShowDialog();
       if (userResp != DialogResult.Cancel)
       {
             pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = pdfSaveDialog.FileName;
              pd = rep.C1Document.Document; 
                    pd.Print();
       }
 }
```

Here are some images.
[  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp81E.png][1]

User clicks print button.Then my customized SaveFileDialog appears.
[  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9gW9.png][2]

After user clicking Save button, another SaveFileDialog appears with default File Name and it actually do printing process. But file name cannot be set.
[  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V5ik.png][1]

Comment: Do you want user to press pri?nt and then they select file

Comment: No ! I want to print the existing report file.

Comment: Then where is need for SaveFileDialog?

Comment: When user choose Printers like Cute PDF,then SaveFileDialog appears.

Comment: But if the file exists why do you open SaveFileDialog it is for saving files,use OpenFileDialog to open a file.

Comment: This code works. When the save file dialog is shown, the "MyNewReport" filename is displayed.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield that is kinda my question becouse it works but i think his question is kinda unclear.

Comment: Maybe use userResp == DialogResult.OK ?

Comment: @VukUskokovic I create the report in the program. And user can print this report by clicking print button. Then print dialog appears. The problem is when user choose printers like "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" or "CutePDF", then OpenFileDialog is automatically appears.Not by my code. I can't set the File Name for that automatically appears "SaveFileDialog".It always show default name.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Yep !! But another SaveFileDialog appears when Save button of "MyNewReport" is clicked.

Comment: Can you post all of the code for the print button click handler?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I add some images to my question and the code in my question are all of the code in the print buuton clicked event.

Comment: Why are you reassigning your `pd` variable to a different document before you print it?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield It is just testing. Whether pd variable is reassigned or not , the result is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I can't duplicate this on my machine.

Comment: First save the file then print it?

Comment: The second dialog is generated by the XPS printer driver.  Which is surely unhappy about you selecting a filename in a directory that cannot be written to.  Fall in the pit of success by setting the  pdfSaveDialog.InitialDirectory property to the user's home folder, like the XPS driver did.  Use Environment.GetFolderPath().